# cannot publish my github page at the correct address

Tags: github-pages

I am trying to set up my personal page on Github.

However, my page is only published at: https://xuxy09.github.io/xuxy09/, while the desired address is https://xuxy09.github.io.

Could you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Issue addressed. The repository name should be "xuxy09.github.io" instead of "xuxy09".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Issue addressed. The repository name should be "xuxy09.github.io" instead of "xuxy09".

That is described in "[Types of GitHub Pages sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)"

> - To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<username>.github.io`.
> - Unless you're using a custom domain, project sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<repository>`

In your case, a repo named `xuxy09` is a *Project* site.
While `xuxy09.github.io` would be, indeed, a User site.